# When using Canvas.drawPath method to draw a large number of paths, the UI freezes

Tags: java, android

The scene is as follows：

I decode the audio data in the video file through MediaCodec. After getting the data of each frame in the audio, I normalize the data to a floating point value through a specific algorithm, and finally get a floating point array (when the video is very long, The array is huge).

Then pass the array into the custom view for waveform drawing, the value of the array is used as the Y coordinate, and the left side of X is incremented by a fixed value. These paths are connected through the rLineTo of drawPath, but because the array value is too large, there are hundreds of thousands Which causes the user interface to freeze

Comment: This really begs for a [mre], but from what you have: "hundreds of thousands of paths" is way too many to draw in one frame.  Phones have gotten quite powerful, but there's still a limit.

Comment: My scene has so many paths, is there any way to optimize it?

Comment: Again, this really depends exactly what you're doing, which is far from clear from your question.  You may be able to render it off the main thread and then cache the result, showing some sort of loading indicator while rendering it.  Basically, anything you can do to avoid redrawing every path every frame is going to help.

Comment: I re-described my scene, please help me to answer it, thank you

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like the sort of thing where you're going to want to do the rendering off the main thread somehow.  The exact way to do that is a bit outside my area of expertise, though, but hopefully that's at least a pointer in the right direction.